# Making a circle in an array (Tile based game light map)

Tags: java, arrays, tile

I am making a tiled based game in java and I want to make a light map.

I am having some issues. I have the lightmap array that has lights placed on it that affect the array. Lights emit in a circle shape. It seems ok so far but its not exactly what I wanted.

Here is my code so far:

```
for(float i = 0; i < strength + 1; i++){
    for(double u = 0.0f; u < 360; u += 0.5){
        double angle = u * Math.PI / 180;
        int x2 = (int)(x + i * Math.cos(angle));
        int y2 = (int)(y + i * Math.sin(angle));
        if(map[y2][x2] > 1 - 1 / i)
            map[y2][x2] = 1 - 1 / i;
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

As you can see in the result, it seems as though the light is expanding too much on the bottom left side (red x's). How do I fix this?

**Background info:**

> Strength:
>   The radius of how far the light reaches. This also
>   determines how bright the light will be at each tile of the array.
>
> The Array "map" is a 2D float array. The engine I am using uses float
>   values for the alpha channel. The range is 0 (completely transparent)
>   to 1 (completely opaque).

**Solution (Thanks to Gene):**

```
for(int x2 = -strength; x2 <= strength; x2++){
    for (int y2 = -strength; y2 <= strength; y2++) {
        double r = Math.sqrt(x2 * x2 + y2 * y2);
        double inv_rad = r <= strength + 1 ? 1 / r : 0;
        if(map[y + y2][x + x2] > 1 - (float) inv_rad)
            map[y + y2][x + x2] = 1 - (float) inv_rad;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add another image showing your expected result? And preferably having only one light source, for both your current result and expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your algorithm suffers from integer truncation of the map indicies. Try it the other away around. Compute the distance from each pixel in a square surrounding the center to the center. From this distance calculate what the intensity ought to be. It will be something like this:

```
for (x = -R; x <= R; x++)
  for (y = -R; y <= R; y++) {
    double r = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    double inv_rad = r <= R ? 1 / r : 0; // truncate outside radius R
    map[yc + y][xc + x] = 1 - inv_rad;
  }
```

Here xc and yc are the integer center coordinates. R is the half-size of the box around the center.

Comment: I am somewhat confused on what variables represent what. Is R the radius of the circle and r the radius reached so far?

Comment: `R` is probably equivalent to `strength`

Comment: Thank you! It works much better now. I slightly modified it to fit my setup. I put it in my question. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

when i try to add this to my project i only get o.o back 
the values i entered where 500, 500,50

```
private float map[][] = new float[1000][1000];

 public void test(int x, int y, float strength){
    public void addLight(int x,int y,int strength ){
    for(int x2 = -strength; x2 <= strength; x2++){
        for (int y2 = -strength; y2 <= strength; y2++) {
            double r = Math.sqrt(x2 * x2 + y2 * y2);
            double inv_rad = r <= strength + 1 ? 1 / r : 0;
            if(map[y + y2][x + x2] > 1 - (float) inv_rad)
                map[y + y2][x + x2] = 1 - (float) inv_rad;
            System.out.println(map[y + y2][x + x2]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment, when it says "Post an answer" that's what it means, not a question. First off, that solution doesn't work. Check the one I posted under "Solution (Thanks to Gene)" and also check Gene's answer. There's a reason why I got an error with that algorithm, reproducing it won't do anything.

Comment: sorry i psoted the wrong method but when u use the new one i still get 0

Comment: @vedi0boy but i cant comment yet and i changed the method so now it show ths right

Comment: :) You can't have a method within a method... Either way, it does work. You have to look at each part of the code carefully. As you can see the "if" statement: `if(map[y + y2][x + x2] > 1 - (float) inv_rad)` checks if what is currently there is darker (higher value) than before. by default, when you created the float array, everything is a 0.0 meaning nothing can get lighter and the condition is never met. Try removing it to test.